# update_by_query with upsert python elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-bulk-api, elasticsearch-helpers

I wish to do an `update_by_query` request using my python elasticsearch client. I wish to query with index, type and a field which is NOT `id`. Based on that field I wish to update some of the other fields but if that query returns no results, a new document should be created with the aforementioned index and type.

I could do a search and then update but I wish to do this with one query only. Also I would like to execute multiple such operations using `helpers.bulk(es, result)` where `es` is the elasticsearch clientand `result` is a list of jsons. Elasticsearch Version is 5.4

Comment: Can we see what you have done so far and where you are blocked?

Comment: @asettouf I am blocked in the sense I can't find any documentation or exxample on how to implement the above whatsoever

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @SagnikSinha, there's no documentation on this. Wondering if it is possible even outside the python dsl

Comment: Painless scripting could do the job if python doesn't work for you

Comment: @cluis92 Any resources or snippets in the mentioned direction, IMO painless inline scripting will be executed on the queried documents that are available in the index

Comment: @SagnikSinha I understand it's been long since this query has been open, Any luck that you have got it worked?